# Get iteration count of for...of loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How do I get the current iteration count of my `for...of` loop?

```
let iterable = new Set([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]);

let i = 0;
for (let value of iterable) {
  console.log('value in Iteration count = ' + i + ' is :' + value);
  i++;
}
```

This is what I currently have, is there some kind of built in iteration count variable which can replace my variable `i`?